# how to display the value from store in vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuex4

I stored my data in Vuex store. Here how it looks like:

[image]

And basically, I want to show first_name in the view. So I returned the data like this:

```
data () {
        return {
            first_name: this.$store.state.user.attributes.first_name,
        }
    },
```

Ans easily want to display it inside of the div:

```
<div>{{first_name}}</div>
```

But I am getting **vue.esm.js:1906 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'first_name')**

Answer (score 1):

You need a computed property for that.

So instead of having the variable `first_name` in your `data`, set it as a computed property as follows:

`computed: { first_name() { return this.$store.state.user.attributes.first_name } }`

Comment: but I want to change first_name variable direcly

Comment: you want to change the variable or display the value as stated on the title of the question? Please update your question so we can understand what you want